# Vagrant+Chef symlink public folder to another folder

Tags: vagrant, symlink

I wonder if its possible to symlink the public folder in a Vagrant / Chef setup so that it points to another folder.

e.g. I have my working directory ~/home/work/site 
and I create a Vagrant setup at ~/home/work/vm

I would like to symlink ~/home/work/vm/public to ~/home/work/site

Is this possible or do I need to have all the files in the Vagrant folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is missing the details what you are really trying to do (as making symlinks on the host has nothing to do with Vagrant), but I guess you want to access the ~/home/work/site directory from the virtual machine. In this case read the [synced folder documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html). For example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder "../site", "/vagrant/public"
end
```

Of course you can select the guest path as you want. And even disable the default mount if you want (`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true`).